# Export and import data from one MySQL DB to an other within the same AWS RDS instance

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I have a RDS MySQL instance created in my AWS account, with multiple databases, one for each environment: production, testing, development.

What I want to accomplish is an automatic process that makes a dump of my production DB, and import it into my testing and development databases.

I've been trying to do it using a Lambda with nodejs, using child_process.exec with a code similar to this:

```js
const dumpCommand = `/opt/mysqldump -h ${dbConfig.host} -P ${dbConfig.port} -u ${dbConfig.user} ` +
            `-p ${dbConfig.password} --set-gtid-purged=OFF ${myDBExport} > /tmp/production_dump.sql`;
            

// Execute mysqldump to create a dump of the production database
await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    exec(dumpCommand, async (dumpError, dumpStdout, dumpStderr) => {
        if (dumpError) {
            console.error('Error creating dump:', dumpError);
            reject(dumpError)
        }

        console.log('Production database dump created.');

        const importCommandTest = `/opt/mysqlimport -h ${dbConfig.host} -P ${dbConfig.port} -u ${dbConfig.user} ` +
            `-p${dbConfig.password} ${myDBImport} < /tmp/production_dump.sql`;

        // Execute MySQL client to import the dump into the database
        await new Promise ((resolveImport, rejectImport) => {
            exec(importCommandTest, (importError, importStdout, importStderr) => {
                if (importError) {
                    console.error(`Error importing dump into ${myDBImport}:`, importError);
                    reject(importError)
                }

                console.log(`Production data imported into ${myDBImport}.`);
                resolveImport();
            });
        });
        resolve();
    });
});
```

Also have a layer associated with my Lambda, containing mysqldump and mysqlimport binaries, and some other dependencies for these binary files. All these files, I copied them from an EC2 Amazon Linux instance. Then I created an ENV VARIABLE to tell lambda where to search for lib files: **LD_LIBRARY_PATH = '/opt'**

But then I got stuck with this error, which **libc.so.6** file I have already in my layer:

> /bin/sh: relocation error: /opt/libc.so.6: symbol _dl_exception_create, version GLIBC_PRIVATE not defined in file ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 with link time reference

**What can I do to solve this?**

*Or*

**Is there a more simple way to achieve it?**

Maybe I am overcomplicating all the process, and all I have to do is create one RDS instance for each environment, but I am trying to avoid increment of costs.

Thanks in advance for your help :)

Comment: Anyone got any ideas?